# HyperLink field in Gridview (Url Navigation)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

At work there is a gridview and it has the following syntax

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField 
    DataNavigateUrlFields="NameID" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="names.aspx?nameid={0}"
    DataTextField="name" 
    HeaderText="Client Name" 
    SortExpression="Name" 
    ItemStyle-Width="100px"
    ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
```

So I added the line DataNavigateUrlFormatString... The link is showing properly but the address looks like this

```
http://.....clients/clientNames/names.aspx?nameid=123
```

This gridview is in the ClientsNames folder.. but I actually want to use the names.aspx of the maintenance folder... so Basically i want the URL to redirect like this

```
httpL//....clients/Maintenance/names.aspx?nameid=123
```

I tried to add DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Maintenance/names.aspx?nameid={0}" but instead it would create url like this

```
http://......clients/clientNames/Mainteanance/names.aspx?nameid=123
```

How can I make it so that the url looks like this from this grid view?

```
http://.....clients/Maintenance/names.aspx?nameid=123
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks guys a vote for all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting DataNavigateUrlFormatString to "../Maintenance/names.aspx?nameid={0}"

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField      
  DataNavigateUrlFields="NameID"
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../maintenance/names.aspx?nameid={0}"
  DataTextField="name"
  HeaderText="Client Name"
  SortExpression="Name"
  ItemStyle-Width="100px"
  ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
```

Comment: i did this, i mentioned in the post

Comment: with the ../ in front of maintenance?

Comment: nothing else, just "../" followed by "maintenance/names.aspx?nameid={0}"

Comment: You may want to do "~/../maintenance/names.aspx..."

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/clients/Maintenance/names.aspx?nameid={0}"
```

Or you can use GridView.RowDataBound event and set Url programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

There's all kinds of wierd prefixes to try...  I don't have a reference off-hand, but here are some:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/names.aspx?nameid={0}" (starts at the root)
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../names.aspx?nameid={0}" (starts in the parent's parent folder)
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../../names.aspx?nameid={0}" (starts in the parent's parent's parent's folder)
```